# Übersetzung von "academia"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> Do you want to work in **academia** or industry after you graduate?

Wie kann man den Satz am besten übersetzen?

Ich habe zwei [Übersetzungen](http://www.dict.cc/?s=academia) von "academia" gefunden: "Akademia" und "die akademische Welt". Die erste Übersetzung ist allerdings als "gehoben" und "selten" markiert. Die zweite könnte zwar funktionieren, wirkt in der Übersetzung dieses Satzes aber ein bisschen umständlich:

> Wollen Sie **in der akademischen Welt** oder in der Industrie arbeiten, nachdem Sie einen Abschluss machen?

Gibt es andere alternative Übersetzungen?

Comment: _In der Wissenschaft_? Statt _Industrie_ eventuell auch eher _in der Wirtschaft_.

Comment: _Im akademischen Bereich_ würde funktionieren. _In der Lehre_ auch, wobei das eigentlich nur einen Aspekt darstellt. Stimme @chirlu zu, dass _in der Wirtschaft_ das geläufige Begriffspaar dazu ist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Üblich sind folgende Formulierungen:

> 1. Wollen Sie **in der Wissenschaft** ... arbeiten ...?
> 2. Wollen Sie **im Wissenschaftsbetrieb** ... arbeiten ...?
> 3. Wollen Sie **in der Forschung** ... arbeiten ...?
> 4. Wollen Sie **an einer Uni/Universität** ... arbeiten ...?

Dabei ist aber Nr. 3 (Forschung) nicht ganz eindeutig, weil man auch in der Industrie forschen kann.

Eine alternative Formulierung von Nr. 4 ist auch:

> 4. Wollen Sie (weiter) an einer Uni/Universität **bleiben** oder in die Industrie **gehen** ...?

Comment: _Universität_ ist streng genommen auch nicht ganz korrekt, weil es auch nichtuniversitäre Einrichtungen wie (in Deutschland) die Max-Planck-Institute gibt. Man würde es aber trotzdem so sagen. :-)